# Поиск совпадений по базе и подстановка найденного в сообщение. Помогите реализовать.

Tags: php

Есть задача, публиковать название трека играющего на радио в твиттер - реализовано, работает отлично.

Вопрос в другом - нужно добавить возможность обращения в твиттер автора публикуемого трека, например: играет трек **Armin van Buuren - Intense** нужно чтобы к нему добавлялся из базы **@arminvanbuuren** таким образом в твиттер ленту отправлялось уже следующее **Armin van Buuren - Intense @arminvanbuuren #trance #trancefamily**

т.е. нужно сделать поиск по совпадению в базе диджеев, только точному совпадению.

Помогите решить задачу, логику я понимаю, но знаний в php не хватает..

Comment: у вас с запросом проблема?

Comment: да это я сделать могу, просто я не понимаю как сравнить название трека **Armin van Buuren - Intense ** с всеми данными в таблице и чтобы он нашел совпадения.